# Some questions about prologue/calling a function gcc intel x86

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I dont quiet understand the gcc prologue, especially for main.
Why is there the instruction `and esp, 0xfffffff0` ? I know what it does but why is it necessary ?

When we call a function, we first have to push the arguments, but why gcc doesn't use the push instruction and uses movs instead ? Moreover using those movs, it creates an empty padding. It looks like a waste of memory, why so ?

Finally, gcc first uses the sub instruction to esp in order to "reserve" memory for the stack, but what makes sure that this memory is not used by on other program for instance ?

I think I understood quiet well the theory, but I couldnt find a document that explains more about memory in pratice (how do memory of several programs dont overlap, ...). Thank you for your answers.

PS : I add the assembly code and the cpp code :

```
    Dump of assembler code for function main(int, char**):
0x08048657 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x08048658 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x0804865a <+3>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x0804865d <+6>:     sub    esp,0x20
   0x08048660 <+9>:     mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x3
   0x08048668 <+17>:    mov    BYTE PTR [esp+0x1b],0x61
=> 0x0804866d <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048771
   0x08048674 <+29>:    call   0x804863c <p(char*)>
   0x08048679 <+34>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0804867e <+39>:    leave  
   0x0804867f <+40>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int b = 3;
  char c = 'a';
  p("hello woooooooooorld !!");}
```

Comment: `gcc -O0` doesn't even use `xor eax, eax` as a zeroing idiom?  :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack alignment is only done for `main`, the rest of the functions just keep the alignment required by the ABI.

The compiler uses `mov` instructions for locals so they can be accessed randomly. For outgoing function arguments you can ask for `push` instructions using the `-mpush-args` compiler option which might produce smaller code.

As for the wasted memory, you probably didn't compile with optimizations enabled (which would of course eliminate your `b` and `c` altogether since they are not used ;))

Each process has its own virtual memory address space, so there is no chance of anybody else using the memory allocated from the stack.

Comment: "wasted memory":  I think he's talking about the fact that every arg takes 4B on the stack, even if it's a narrower type.  @x4rkz: this is required by the ABI.  Reasons include: maintaining stack alignment, and sending args to the same place regardless of their type.  Your example doesn't demonstrate this, though.  Either that or he's talking about the gap between where the locals are stored and where the function arg went.  That's to maintain stack alignment.

Comment: Thank you, I understood most of it, I understood why the alignment is required thanks to this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment, apparently it is hardware-related. I just didn't understand what you mean buy "they can be acceessed randomly"

Comment: @Peter thank for your comment, as soon as I understood the purpose of stack alignment it all became clear to me. I needed an actual reason and I have one.

Comment: @x4rkz: "accessed randomly": you could initially `push` locals onto the stack.  Once they're there, you'd access them by their offset from `esp`, rather than with `pop`.  Pushing them would be a micro-optimization for a special case, which you certainly don't get with `-O0`.  Also, `push` will make the next `mov eax, [esp + 1c]` slower, because the stack engine will have to insert an extra uop to sync `esp` with the stack-engine's internal offset.  (http://agner.org/optimize/).  Since `main` already used `esp` with an `and` instruction, that price was already paid, so `push` has a slight cost.